# Are there any services which can check the amount of load a website can take? say a 100,000 hits per day

Tags: performance

i need a way to check my websites performance for more than at least a 100,000 hits per day. I dont want to be caught offguard during spikes of visitors to the website.

So is there any way i can check for website performance. any scripts, programs software which i can use for offline/online testing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools out of here, Apache provides a tool called "ApacheBench", Wikipedia has a list of alternatives.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking#Tools_for_benchmarking

Example usage:

```
ab -c 5 -n 1000 http://example.com/
```

- `-c 5`: five concurrent requests, that is five requests at a time.
- `-n 1000`: do a total of 1000 requests
- `http://example.com/`: the page you want to request

Answer (score 0):

No services, sorry. Applicaitons you can install locally and test things in your network. Note that 100.000 hits PER DAY is NOTHING. Like really nothing. Equally distributed over 4 (!) hours that would be 6.9444 (a little less than 7) hits PER SECOND. Distribute it evenly over a day and we talk of 1.16 (nearly one and a quarter) hits per second. My mobile phone can handle that.

Comment: so is a shared server good enough or do i need a dedicated one just in case. maybe the cloud ??.

Comment: No idea. Depends how much processing you do per hit. Normally I would say the cheapest shared site would be plenty.